# JQuery - Works in Firefox, but not in Safari, Chrome, or Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code. It works wonderfully in Firefox, but I can't seem to get it to work on any other browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".poem").click(function () {
        $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.showContent').slideToggle(300)
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("slow", function ()
        $('html').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 25
        }, "fast"));
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the expected action? does the console say anything? can you create a jsfiddle or codepen? what is the html?

Comment: Please post a complete code example. Also, a stack snippet would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $('html').animate try using $('html, body').animate.